# HTTP GET request in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb, swift

This one is killing me! Long story short, I am running a Node.js server that communicates to a Mongo Database. I have been very successful with submitting data with HTTP POST(and see the results), but for the life of me I am failing with GET requests.

My code:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://*******/users/userlist")
let requestGet = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
var response: NSURLResponse?

requestGet.HTTPMethod = "GET"
requestGet.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(requestGet, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
{(response, data, error) in

println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

I am able to step through the code above, but for some reason when I hit "NSURLConnection" Xcode completely ignores the 'println', which is somthing I cannot explain.

I know I'm doing something pretty stupid....

Comment: Are you sure it's not a server-side problem?

Comment: did you already checked the error?

Comment: Have you already used a tool like this to confirm that the request should work: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-resource-test/

Comment: I was able to confirm a successful GET request using Advance Rest client and I was able to receive content... No Idea why my code above doesn't work(FYI I receive no errors).

Comment: Try removing the Accept header you have defined here. The `application/json` value could be confusing your server because GET requests will never have JSON POST data

Comment: @user1968307 Im getting the exact same problem , the get request aren't working while the post requests are working and the weird thing is when I test the requests using postman they all work fine!